# My ipad 3 is asking money for free apps

Tags: ipad

I was downloading clash royale . First it asked me my password.
Then it said verification required for app purchase.
I can download the apps which i have downloaded before and deleted.[image]

Comment: It won't charge for the free apps, but for some reason, you must have a payment method to; I think it's because whoever programed it forgot to say 'don't ask for payment methods if the app is free'

Answer (score 1):

You must have a valid payment method in your account, even for free apps.